# IoException error when save button is selected

Tags: c#, winforms

Beloew is my code which i want to save some info the user key in to be saved to the file, how come i keep encountering Ioexception error after i debug and click on the save button..pls kindly adv..thks!!! i guess it has something to do with the filefolder but have absolutely no idea..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ASSISNMENTTT
{
    public partial class Registeration : Form
    {
        public Registeration()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This is the button labeled "Save" in the program.
            //
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\demo.txt", Tb_Admin.Text);
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\demo.txt", Tb_Name.Text);
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\demo.txt", Tb_Gender.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give the stack trace and the exception message?

Comment: Try saving the file to a different location, like inside your user profile.  You may not have write access to C:\

Comment: As someone pointed out on my deleted answer - you get a UnauthorizedAccessException if there is a permission issue, not an IOException. My memory must be going!

Comment: Access to the path 'C:\demo.txt' is denied.

Comment: unauthorisied access exception was unhandled

Comment: so must i create a folder in c drive name the folder demo?? bcos i have not created any folder yet..and i dun think e issue lies with momory or watsoever..pls kindly adv..thks!!!!

Comment: You are not allow by Windows to write files to every location on the hard drive.  You need to choose a location where you have write access.  Any folder underneath your user account (inside c:\Users or c:\documents and settings) will work.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are on Win7 or Vista and have no access to the c:\ drive.

Comment: Access to the path 'C:\demo.txt' is denied.

Comment: @Jun, so yes, I am correct.  By default, you do not have access to the root directory of the c drive.  Try saving the file to c:\users\{your_user_name}\desktop\demo.txt

Comment: Hi Angry hacker..your user name would refer to the name of my pc?

Comment: @Jun, it refers to your user name

Answer (score 0):

If your app does have access to the C:\ drive, demo.txt is likely marked read-only as [`WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) will attempt to overwrite the file.

This code shows an UnauthorizedAccessException with the same error text as you are commenting on your question and on the other answer.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var demoTxt = new FileInfo("C:\\demo.txt");
    demoTxt.Attributes |= FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

    WriteAllText("should succeed");


    try
    {
        demoTxt.Attributes |= FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
        WriteAllText("should fail");
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(uae.ToString());
    }
}

static void WriteAllText(string text)
{
    // This is the button labeled "Save" in the program.
    //
    File.WriteAllText("C:\\demo.txt", text);
}
```

For future reference, this may help you give more information for SO posts.

```
    private void Btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // This is the button labeled "Save" in the program.
            //
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\demo.txt", Tb_Admin.Text);
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\demo.txt", Tb_Name.Text);
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\demo.txt", Tb_Gender.Text);
        }
        catch(IoException ex)
        {
            //View the Output Window, copy the text to your question
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi  Austin, Must i first create a new folder in c drive named demo first?

Comment: No folder is necessary.  The file being read-only is an option based on your comments.

Comment: im still encountering the same error which im nt sure where went wrong..but many thks to u Austin for the help u render